# Adding dynamically an Ember Component inside external jQuery plugin

Tags: ember.js

I am using some external jQuery plugin which creates some modal (dateRangePicker). After this I want to add dynamically a component inside the newly created modal (some form element). Is this even possible? For example, in Angular I would use `$compile('<div my-directive></div>')`...

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to build the modal with an Ember component and have it interface with the plugin.

Something along the lines of:

```
import Plugin from '';

App.FoobarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['jquery-modal'], // or whatever needed

  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.$... // initialize plugin
  },

  actions: {
    someUserInteraction: function() {
      Plugin.someFunction();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but unfornately it is hard to implement all those actions, I have components for some input fields, range-slider, etc. which i want to add in this jquery modal. In your way i would have to repeat all the logic which i was using in those components... Because the components are based on some binded properties rather than normal actions. Generaly I am implementing the jquery modal like in your example, and I wanted to use in didInsertElement: Ember.$... (init plugin) and then Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', addDynamicallyEmberComponentsToSomeDOMElements)